# textmate HTML tag highlighting like notepad++?

Tags: html, textmate, highlighting

in notepad++ there is a nifty add-on that highlights the matching tag in HTML (so for example, if i click on a  it highlights that closing tag as well as the opening  tag that it's matched to). is there a way to do this in textmate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945069/textmate-select-and-modify-matching-html-tags) may be of at least some use.